Python: type hinting for decorating custom dataclass with inheritance
Here's the situation. I'm trying to reduce the amount of boilerplate code in my project. Here is a simplified version of the setup.
from __future__ import annotations

import dataclasses
import typing as t
import types

_Self = t.TypeVar("_Self", bound="A")

class A:
  """Base class for all classes"""
  @classmethod
  def create(cls: type[_Self], *args, **kwargs) -> _Self:
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)

  def do_something(self) -> None:
    """a 'void' method"""
    pass


class B(A):
  """A secondary base class for the future dataclasses; NOTE: inheritance from A!"""


T = t.TypeVar("T", bound=B)
TCallable = t.Callable[[type], type[T]]


def decorator(**kwargs) -> TCallable:
  """A decorator for reducing boilerplate"""
  def _decorator(cls: type) -> type[B]:
    return types.new_class(
      cls.__name__, 
      (
        dataclasses.dataclass(**{"frozen": True, "kw_only": True, **kwargs}(cls), 
        B,
      ),
    )
  return _decorator


@decorator(repr=False)
class Test:
   """This is an implementation of the dataclass, subclassed from B, subclassed from A"""
   name: str
   
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
      return self.name
    
    def do_something_else(self) -> None:
      self.do_something() # <- not recognized by pyright

The problem is that my static type checker is unable to recognize the methods from class A at the top of the resolution order from within instances of class Test.
I'm using Pylance/Pyright in VSCode.
Edited to correct error in decorator

decorator needs to return _decorator.  Not sure if that's the only problem.

@chepner thanks for the response, this was something I accidentally left out when I was making a minimum working example for discussion. I've updated the question. Thanks!

Two observations: if I add a call to Test().do_something() to the end of the script, pyright complains about that as well. But, if I replace TCallable with Callable[[type], type[B]], then pyright only complains about self.do_something. That suggests there's an issue with the alias, but that pyright also type-checks Test before taking the decorator into account.

That's an interesting observation.

I'm wondering if this is even possible. I've been reviewing this bug discussion, and it would seem, based on that, the static type checkers would not be able to infer from the dynamic creation of the class.

It seems like pyright could use @decorator for context as much as it uses the class statement as well. There could be issues in doing so that I'm not aware of.

This is way too much metaprogramming for a static typechecker. You could benefit from @dataclass_transform, but it still won't solve all your problems. You cannot express this in statically typing python. You have to pay something for type hinting, and sometimes quite a lot. You can a) write a mypy plugin (won't help pyright, but at least one of major typecheckers will understand you), b) ditch this and inherit explicitly and c) just stop trying to fit this into type hints - they are not mandatory and can sometimes be harmful for a beatiful design.

First, I should note it can be implemented without the decorator like so:
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen = True, kw_only = True, repr=False)
class Test(B):
   """This is an implementation of the dataclass, subclassed from B, subclassed from A"""
   name: str
   
   def __repr__(self) -> str:
      return self.name
    
   def do_something_else(self) -> None:
      self.do_something()

But let's assume, that for some reason it needs to be there. This example assumes that you just wanted to avoid typing frozen and kw_only many times:
from __future__ import annotations

import dataclasses
import typing as t

_Self = t.TypeVar("_Self", bound="A")

class A:
  """Base class for all classes"""
  @classmethod
  def create(cls: type[_Self], *args, **kwargs) -> _Self:
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)

  def do_something(self) -> None:
    """a 'void' method"""
    pass

class B(A):
  """A secondary base class for the future dataclasses; NOTE: inheritance from A!"""

@t.dataclass_transform()
def decorator(**kwargs):
  def _decorator(cls: type) -> type[B]:
    return dataclasses.dataclass(**{"frozen": True, "kw_only": True, **kwargs})(cls)
  return _decorator


@decorator(repr=False)
class Test(B):
   """This is an implementation of the dataclass, subclassed from B, subclassed from A"""
   name: str
   
   def __repr__(self) -> str:
      return self.name
    
   def do_something_else(self) -> None:
      self.do_something()

The inheritance aspect is impossible to add into the type currently, which is why I've left it inheriting from B. In general this is probably better practice anyway, as it makes the inheritance structure clearer. However, this may eventually be possible to type with Intersection. Hope this is useful!
